# Manipulating time series with different start dates

Tags: pandas, time-series

I'm a novice Python programmer and I have an issue that I was hoping you could help me with.

I have two time series in Pandas, but they start at different dates. Let's say one starts in 1989, and the other in 2002. Now I want to to compare the cumulative growth of the two, by indexing both series to 2002 (the first time period where I have data for both), and calculate the ratio.

What is the best way to go about it? Ideally, the script should check what's the earliest available data for a pair of series and index both to 100 from that point onward.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

A practical solution may be to split the dataframe into two columns, one for each time series, and add a 'monthyear' column to each dataframe, that only lists the month and year (e.g. 05-2015). Then, you can use pd.merge on both dataframe on that month variable, keeping only the rows that have overlapping months in which they occur. The function would be `pd.merge(df1, df2, on='monthyear', how='inner')`

You can split the pandas dataframe by creating a new dataframe and loading in only 1 column (or row, depending on how your dataframe looks like). `df1 = pd.Dataframe(original_dataframe[0])` and `df2 = pd.Dataframe(original_dataframe[1])`